# C# file browse to textbox.text only .doc .txt etc

Tags: c#, file, textbox, doc

I am trying to browse for .doc, .text, etc file and paste location to textbox3.text. I am getting underlines and I don't know what I missed.

here is code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog bDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    bDialog.Title = "Open Word or Text File";
    bDialog.Filter = "Text Files|*.doc;*.docx;*.txt;*.text";
    bDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    if (bDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
    File2Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(bDialog.FileName.ToString());
    }
    textBox3.Text = File2Lines;
}
```

and image with underlines:
http://shrani.si/f/3J/bu/2ALFViEN/missing.png

Any solution? (if something doesn't make any sense it's because I am noob)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't declared `File2Lines` as a variable.  Also, `ReadAllLines` returns a `String[]` and not a `string`.  Try:

```
string[] File2Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(bDialog.FileName.ToString());
```

then

```
textBox3.Lines = File2Lines;
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter - the red squiggly in the image indicates it hasn't been declared.